# How to create an instance of the COM object in C#?

Tags: c#, com

Visual Basic has a `GetObject` function, which can be used like this

```
Set app = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```

1C Enterprise also has an `new COMObject()` operator, which also takes a plain string and returns a corresponding COM object.

What's the C# equivalent for this function?

Comment: VB by default isn't Type safe, c# is, generally you have to have to generate an interop wrapper to type safe a Com object before you can use it in c#, See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404285(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the same `GetObject` function in `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace. Haven't satisfied with this, I've decompiled that function and found how it creates COM objects: [`Marshal.GetActiveObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Activator.CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx).

To reflect on COM objects one can use [`IDispatch::GetTypeInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc1ec9aa-6c40-4e70-819c-a7c6dd6b8c99) method from Oleauto.h. There is also a neat wrapper for C# on [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/523417/Reflection-with-IDispatch-based-COM-objects).

Some objects, like 1C Automation ("V83.Application") doesn't seem to work with C#'s `dynamic` right away. To deal with that I've created a class and inherited from `System.Dynamic.DynamicObject`. This allowed me to override `InvokeMethod` and call `IDispatch::Invoke` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Activator.CreateInstance(string Progid)` method to create a COM Object by passing the Prog id of the COM Class